# Replace foreach with lambda with optional

Tags: lambda, java-8, option-type

I'm trying to rewrite this piece of code:

```
Integer lastValidIndex = 0;
if (value != null) {
    for(Entry<Key, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Integer cur = entry.getValue();
        if (cur != null) {
            if( cur > value ) break;
            lastValidIndex = entry.getKey().getIndex();
        }
    }
}
return lastValidIndex;


return Optional.ofNullable(score).map(paramValue -> {
  Optional<Entry<PathwaysProgressType, Integer>> optionalEntry = 
        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > paramValue)
           .findFirst();

  return optionalEntry
         .map(entry -> entry.getKey().getIndex())
         .orElse(0);
}).orElse(0);
```

Could you please help me find the bug? Seems like, it works fine, but not.

Comment: Is your Map a `SortedMap`?

Comment: can you explain us what you are trying to do ? Please post the complete code

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to find the last valid index, here is a valid solution :

```
return Optional.ofNullable(score).map(paramValue -> 
     map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter( entry -> entry.getValue() <= paramValue )
        .map( entry -> entry.getKey().getIndex() )
        .reduce( (previousIndex, curIndex) -> curIndex )
        .orElse(0)
).orElse(0);
```

You can use the `reduce` function to take the last valid index

Comment: Hi! This doesn't do the same as the imperative code, i.e. try with values `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]` and `value = 3`. The `lastValidIndex` should be the one that corresponds to the first `3` (the one at the 2nd position in the list), while your code returns the index that corresponds to the last `3` (the one at the 6th position in the list).

Comment: so you need to get the first valid index ? just replace `.reduce( (previousIndex, curIndex) -> curIndex )` by `.findFirst()`

Comment: that would return the `lastValidIndex` that corresponds to the first `1` (the one at the 0th position in the list)

Comment: this code doesn't compile

Comment: What is the error ? it compiles on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null && entry.getValue() > paramValue)
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey().getIndex())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(0);
```